# BadValueError: Property xxxx is required, even after the xxxx property has already been set? (google app engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

Here's my model:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext.db import polymodel

class Item(polymodel.PolyModel):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    summary = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    content = db.TextProperty(required=True)
    createDate = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class Article(Item):
    author = db.StringProperty()
```

and my handler:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import models.model

class Test(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        create(100)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Test')
        self.response.out.write('<p>Created')


app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/test/*', Test)], debug=True)

def create(count):
    for i in range(0,count,1):
        article = models.model.Article()
        article.title = "Test title " + str(i)
        article.author = "wliao"
        article.summary = "this is a test " + str(i)
        article.content = "this is the content of the article"
        article.put()    

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My question is, I already set the required properties, why do I still get this error when loaded it in the browser:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wliao/Programming/GoogleAppEngineSDK/google/appengine/ext/webapp/**init**.py", line 700, in **call**
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/home/wliao/Programming/MysteryLeague/src/controllers/test.py", line 8, in get
    create(100)
  File "/home/wliao/Programming/MysteryLeague/src/controllers/test.py", line 18, in create
    article = models.model.Article()
  File "/home/wliao/Programming/GoogleAppEngineSDK/google/appengine/ext/db/**init**.py", line 910, in **init**
    prop.**set**(self, value)
  File "/home/wliao/Programming/GoogleAppEngineSDK/google/appengine/ext/db/**init**.py", line 594, in **set**
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "/home/wliao/Programming/GoogleAppEngineSDK/google/appengine/ext/db/**init**.py", line 2627, in validate
    value = super(UnindexedProperty, self).validate(value)
  File "/home/wliao/Programming/GoogleAppEngineSDK/google/appengine/ext/db/**init**.py", line 621, in validate
    raise BadValueError('Property %s is required' % self.name)
BadValueError: Property content is required

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/datamodeling.html):

> Because validation occurs when the
>   instance is constructed, any property
>   that is configured to be required must
>   be initialized in the constructor.

So:

```
title = "Test title " + str(i)
author = "wliao"
summary = "this is a test " + str(i)
content = "this is the content of the article"

article = models.model.Article(title=title, author=author,
                               summary=summary, content=content)
```