# BadValueError: Property X is required

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've added a list property to an entity model with a large number of existing instances.

```
class MyModel(db.Model):

    new_property = db.ListProperty(item_type=str, default=None)
```

Upon deployment to the live environment the app runs without issues for a short time and then starts throwing BadValueError error's as it tries to retrieve records from the datastore.

The code throwing the error is just a straight call to the datastore:

```
app_item = db.get(app_item_key)
```

I'm using 1.7.5. of the Python 2.7 runtime.

Any ideas on what I can do to prevent this, or at least trap it so that I can get data from the store?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/app/4-15.365909351579418812/app.py", line 1739, in app_get
    app_item = db.get(app_item_key)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1533, in get
    return get_async(keys, **kwargs).get_result()
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 604, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1459, in __get_hook
    entities = rpc.user_data(entities)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 600, in local_extra_hook
    return extra_hook(result)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1503, in extra_hook
    model = cls1.from_entity(entity)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1438, in from_entity
    return cls(None, _from_entity=entity, **entity_values)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 970, in __init__
    prop.__set__(self, value)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 614, in __set__
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 3460, in validate
    value = super(ListProperty, self).validate(value)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 641, in validate
    raise BadValueError('Property %s is required' % self.name)
BadValueError: Property new_property is required
```

**For those that follow:**

As per Aaron D's suggestion, changing the default value to an empty list resolved this issue, so:

```
new_property = db.ListProperty(item_type=str, default=None)
```

Should read:

```
new_property = db.ListProperty(item_type=str, default=[])
```

Comment: Can you post some more relevant code, like your retrieval calls?  Seems like it might be loosely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142439/badvalueerror-property-xxxx-is-required-even-after-the-xxxx-property-has-alrea?rq=1

Comment: This answer may relate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10012905/399704

Comment: In both cases these relate to the required=true being applied to the property, but that's not the case here (although it is behaving as it though it is).

Comment: Submitted as a possible issue for the App Engine guy's: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8962

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code of the Google App Engine in the `__init__.py` referenced in your traceback, you can see a comment in the ListProperty doc comments (line 3428) that says:

> Note that the only permissible value for 'required' is True.

So, even though you are not providing it, it looks like line 3442 is setting it automatically:
`self._require_parameter(kwds, 'required', True)`

If you look further into the source code (line 3500), you can see the definition of `empty()` for a `ListProperty`:

```
def empty(self, value):
    """Is list property empty.

    [] is not an empty value.

    Returns:
      True if value is None, else false.
    """
    return value is None
```

I could think of two issues that might cause error but I haven't verified through testing.

1) If for some reason, you already have data in that field (perhaps you are reusing the `new_property` name?) and it was empty, then it seems likely to generate the error you have.  I am not sure how to fix this problem, except to suggest that you use a unique name for your `new_property` instead.  The [post I referenced in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10012905/399704) explains how to "fix" the data.

2) Since you already have records, your code is trying to populate those using your default value of `None`, which matches the `empty()` test and then throws the exception.  In that case, if you just provide a default value of `[]` instead, it should work.

Comment: See my answer above about how to generate the problem,then if the entity has been written already with a default value of None as a StringProperty, then changing the default value to [] in the model definition for a ListProperty will still get the same BadValueError as in this case the property does exist and has None in it, which is an invalid value for a ListProperty.

Comment: 1) new_property isn't a property, or property name that has been used previously. 2) Changing default=None to default=[] seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you example code here is not what you are using. I would bet you have `required=True` in the new property. You are then retrieving an old record which doesn't have a value for the required property.  Just dropping 'required=True` will make those errors go away. If you need to have that value required then you need to add the default value to the field before enforcing the constraint.

*** removed some complete garbage about `None` not being a valid default value for ListProperty ***

So I tried to replicate the situation based on the information you have supplied
and I have the answer.  I can generate the problem by first creating a model that has a name `new_property` of type StringProperty with a default of None.  put() the record with no value for `new_property getting the default of None written, then change the model definition of new_property to`ListProperty`, and the fetch the record.  We get the same stack trace.  See shell log below.

```
s~lightning-catfish> class MyModel(db.Model):
...   pass
... 
s~lightning-catfish> x = MyModel()
s~lightning-catfish> x.put()
datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'MyModel', 1001L, _app=u's~lightning-catfish')
s~lightning-catfish> class MyModel(db.Model):
...    new_property = db.ListProperty(item_type=str,default=None)
... 
s~lightning-catfish> y = db.get(x.key())
s~lightning-catfish> y
<MyModel object at 0x9e09dcc>
s~lightning-catfish> y.new_property
[]
s~lightning-catfish>    new_property = db.StringProperty(defaul
KeyboardInterrupt
s~lightning-catfish> class MyModel(db.Model):
...    new_property = db.StringProperty(default=None)
... 
s~lightning-catfish> z = MyModel()
s~lightning-catfish> z.put()
datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'MyModel', 2001L, _app=u's~lightning-catfish')
s~lightning-catfish> class MyModel(db.Model):
...    new_property = db.ListProperty(item_type=str,default=None)
... 
s~lightning-catfish> a1 = db.get(z.key())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/timh/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1533, in get
    return get_async(keys, **kwargs).get_result()
  File "/home/timh/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 604, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/home/timh/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1459, in __get_hook
    entities = rpc.user_data(entities)
  File "/home/timh/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 600, in local_extra_hook
    return extra_hook(result)
  File "/home/timh/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1503, in extra_hook
    model = cls1.from_entity(entity)
  File "/home/timh/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1438, in from_entity
    return cls(None, _from_entity=entity, **entity_values)
  File "/home/timh/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 970, in __init__
    prop.__set__(self, value)
  File "/home/timh/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 614, in __set__
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "/home/timh/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 3460, in validate
    value = super(ListProperty, self).validate(value)
  File "/home/timh/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 641, in validate
    raise BadValueError('Property %s is required' % self.name)
BadValueError: Property new_property is required
s~lightning-catfish>
```

To fix the data you will need to access it at a low level and change the data types stored in the record.

I have code for fetching and putting entities without using models if you want it.

*** last thing you should try ***

Try using the following code or something like it to fetch objects without using the model.
You get the underlying data back, with types etc.. in dicts.  That will show you what is in the datastore.

```
from google.appengine.api import datastore
from google.appengine.api import datastore_errors

def get_entities(keys):
    rpc = datastore.GetRpcFromKwargs({})
    keys, multiple = datastore.NormalizeAndTypeCheckKeys(keys)
    entities = None
    try:
        entities = datastore.Get(keys, rpc=rpc)
    except datastore_errors.EntityNotFoundError:
        assert not multiple

    return entities


x = get_entities([some_key])
```

Comment: The example is a direct copy of the property, I'm not using required=true.

Comment: Well something is going on, `because BadValueError: Property new_property is required` is exactly what you get when `required=True`

Comment: ok, None is not a valid default value for a ListProperty, try changing your default to `[]`

Comment: According to the [GAE docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ListProperty), ```None``` *is* a valid default value.  "The value of a ListProperty cannot be None. It can, however, be an empty list. When None is specified for the default argument (or when the default argument is not specified), the default value of the property is the empty list."

Comment: @Aaron, good point and stand corrected, seemed like a logical pregression to understand the OP problem.  Will try it myself see if I can replicate

Comment: This wasn't an existing property that had it's type changed, but a new property.

Comment: Well I give up then ;-)  I can replicate the exact error you have with the above scenario. I have yet to find any way other way of doing it yet.  Have you tried looking at the values in the datastore using the Datastore viewer ? See my earlier edits for some other things I tried.